# How to make a SWT Composite selectable?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, selection, composite

I'm creating a wizard page in eclipse using SWT libraries. So far I have succeeded in creating the page but with only one issue:- **SWT composite doesn't get selected**.
My wizard page contains a scrolledComposite containing multiple composites in a grid fashion. **Each composite contains a browser just like a sample template**. What I want is when I select a composite containing browser it should get selected and the finish button activated.

Now, my doubt is, **how do I make the composite containing the browser selectable as a composite doesn't contain selectionListener. Or better still, is there a way to make a browser selectable?**

Sample code would be appreciated.

I'm a noob and this is my first question on SO so please forgive me for any mistakes in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the `addFocusListener` method of the browser to listen for the control gaining (or losing) the focus. You can then enable/disable the finish button.

The focus listener looks like:

```
public class MyFocusListener implements FocusListener
{
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent event)
  {
  }

  public void focusLost(FocusEvent event)
  {
  }
}
```

Test program:

```
public class Stackoverflow
{
  public static void main(final String args [])
  {
    Display.setAppName("Stackoverflow");
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    shell.setSize(500, 400);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final Browser browser = new Browser(composite, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    final Button finish = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
    finish.setText("Finish");
    finish.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false));

    browser.setUrl("google.com");

    final FocusListener listener = new FocusListener()
      {
        public void focusLost(final FocusEvent arg0)
        {
        }


        public void focusGained(final FocusEvent arg0)
        {
          System.out.println("FocusGained");
          finish.setEnabled(true);
        }
      };
    browser.addFocusListener(listener);

    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
      {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
          display.sleep();
      }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried with the above method but it doesn't work.. Please just check it out :  Composite composite = new Composite (shell, SWT.BORDER);
   composite.setSize (400, 600);
   Browser browser = new Browser(composite, SWT.NONE);final Button finish = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
   finish.setText("Finish");
   browser.setUrl("http://www.google.com");
   FocusListener listener = new FocusListener() {
  public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
  }
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
   System.out.println("FocusGained");finish.setEnabled(true);}
   };
   browser.addFocusListener(listener);

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? What happens, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I expected it to print FocusGained on selection.. Also the website isn't displayed on the browser..

Comment: There are several errors with your code. Your button has a different parent from the browser and doesn't have a valid style. You haven't specified any size or layout for the controls so they are using their minimum sizes. I have added a test program which works for me.

Comment: In test program, when the browser gets focus, neither the button gets enabled(try disabling the button as default and then enabling it through focus) nor the text "FocusGained" is displayed. I want to enable the finish button when the composite/browser is selected as in my case there are multiple browsers and I want to select one based on which my finish button gets enabled accordingly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'selected'? What are you doing to make it 'selected'?

Comment: By selection I mean the Selection event as in the case of TableViewer there is a SelectionChangedListener wherein if a different row in table is selected then it shows selection(colored in blue as opposed to normal white background as well as a Selection event occuring). I haven't done anything to make it selected. I want to make it selected on mouse click.

Comment: There is no such thing for Composite, Selection is only for Buttons, checkboxes and the like. Clicking on the browser should make it the focus control.

Comment: Yet the browser doesn't gain focus! I agree there's nothing as such for composites but "FocusGained" isn't printed nor is the button enabled on browser getting focus.

Comment: Thanks! The browser gets focus with some tweaks now :)

Comment: greg-449, the above code snippet worked with my tweaks on Windows platforms XP, 7; but it doesn't work on Linux platform. The OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Do you know what the error could be?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot @greg-449 for pushing me in the right direction and being patient with me. After doing some research, I found there was a system specific bug due to which it wouldn't reach the FocusListener code. See bug here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=84532

The following code contains workaround through which a SWT Browser can get focus.

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

    Display.setAppName("Stackoverflow");
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    shell.setSize(500, 400);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final Browser browser = new Browser(composite, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    final Button finish = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    finish.setText("Finish");
    finish.setEnabled(false);
    finish.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false));

    browser.setUrl("google.com");

    final FocusListener listener = new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Focus lost");
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Focus gained");
            finish.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };

    /*
     * workaround for bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=84532
     */
    Listener deactivateListener = new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            listener.focusLost(new FocusEvent(event));
        }
    };
    Listener activateListener = new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            listener.focusGained(new FocusEvent(event));
        }
    };

    browser.addListener(SWT.Deactivate, deactivateListener);
    browser.addListener(SWT.Activate, activateListener);

    finish.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e){
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
    });

    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
      {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
          display.sleep();
      }
    display.dispose();

}
```

Now the browser does get focus through which my button gets activated but is there any way to show it as selected?